# Trying to apply a class to a styled-component for an onclick event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

In using standard JSX and CSS, I can add a className attribute with some logic to add a class name based on a boolean value, but when using styled-components, this doesn't appear to be as easy.  This is what I have at the moment:

**Menu.tsx**

```
interface IMenuProps {
  showMenu: boolean;
  menuToggle: () => void;
}

const Menu: React.FC<IMenuProps> = ({ showMenu, menuToggle }) => {
  return (
    <MenuWrapper onClick={menuToggle} {showMenu ? "showMenu" : ""}>
      ...
```

At the moment, there's a red line under the `showMenu` within the ternary statement.

```
'...' expected.
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add className.

```html
const Menu: React.FC<IMenuProps> = ({ showMenu, menuToggle }) => {
  return (
    <MenuWrapper onClick={menuToggle} className={showMenu ? "showMenu" : ""}>
```

BTW:

If there isn't any logic inside your component you can write it as

```html
const Example: FC = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Example</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: lol, I don't know why I didn't think to try that.  I was thinking you couldn't do that with a styled-component, obviously you can.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written types for your styled MenuWrapper?
If not, try something like this:

`const MenuWrapper = styled.div<{showMenu?:boolean}>`